# API version is showing up options from 42 to 47 only.Why am I not able to see the lower api versions?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Previously lightning component api version was only 39. But when I add overlay library component, it was not supported in that version, so I changed it to 42. But It is not working as expected, now I wish to revert back to version 39. But 39 option is not showing up to select that option.

Comment: Did you remove the overlay library component?

Comment: yes. I removed.

Comment: For now what I did is I have deployed  the same component with the api version 39.Now the api version has changed. Its working fine but am not sure why lower versions are not showing up in drop down of developer console bundle version settings.